# Query Selector giving empty Nodelist in my application

Tags: javascript, class, queryselector, setattr

My JS CODE:

```
cell.setAttribute('class','input-cell selected-cell'); //this line is a part of my code.
var input_cell=document.querySelectorAll('.input-cell .selected-cell');
console.log(input_cell)
```

I am building an excel clone and while rendering cells, I gave them Class attribute.Still while
running the querySelectorAll function ,I am getting an empty NodeList.

Comment: Get rid of the space between the classes in the selector. That makes it look for a descendant, not the two classes in the same element.

Comment: BTW, it's better to use the modern `classList` property rather than setting the `class` attribute.

Comment: @Barmar Did that but still it didnt work..

Comment: Please update the question with the relevant section of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I thin you are missing a comma.

```js
const cell = document.getElementById("cell");
cell.setAttribute('class','input-cell selected-cell'); //this line is a part of my code.

const input_cell = document.querySelectorAll('.input-cell, .selected-cell');

console.log('input-cell', input_cell)
```

```html
<div id="cell"></div>
```